# Self Hosted Wordpress Blog cant rotate images uploaded

Tags: php, wordpress, image, digital-ocean

I have purchased hosting on Digital Ocean for my website and wordpress blog.

I have uploaded images from my phone and am trying to write a post, But it will not let me rotate the images when I try to edit them in wordpress. When I click on the image to edit, from the media viewer where the images shows up correctly, it does not show right and the rotate buttons are greyed out:

[image]

Comment: What browser / OS are you using?  I seem to remember that functionality was restricted to a very fine set of browsers

Comment: I am using Chrome on Windows 10

Comment: This isn't really a programming problem.

Comment: @Takendarkk could be depending on what the issues ends up being ;-)

Comment: @Takendarkk it could very well be as it appears to be an issue involving PHP and it's modules.

Answer (score 2):

OK, the error is probably you don't have the required image library installed on the serever.  Assuming you are running ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

Then restart wordpress :)

Comment: Installed without error, still not working. But not sure what you mean by restart wordpress. When the above was installed it restarted the apache server so that should be fine right?

Comment: I meant restart the webserver so as long as apache was restarted should be fine.  Can you make a new php file with the contents `<?php echo phpinfo() ?>` in it.  And then post a screenshot of the output

Comment: SO the output is kind of long, is there a specific section you would like a screenshot of?

Comment: If it's too long run this instead and screenshot it `<?php print_r( gd_info() ); ?>`

Comment: That one didnt return anything

Comment: OK, what is the last line in your wordpress `functions.php`

Comment: Assuming I took this from the file you are refering to in my theme folder: add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'material_gaze_customize_preview_js' );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87941/discussion-between-marshallofsound-and-mike).